# C# Tcp Async Programming

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I try to learn and wrote some code for TCP connection.
This is my Server Class :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Tcp
{
    public class Server
    {
        #region Constructor
        public Server()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region Field

        //Server Socket        
        public Socket SrvSocket;
        //Server Port
        private int _socketPort = 8080;
        byte[] byteData = new byte[1024];
        #endregion


        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Socket Port Int Value
        /// </summary>
        public int SocketPort
        {
            get
            {
                return _socketPort;
            }
            set
            {
                _socketPort = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region Method
        public void Close()
        {
            SrvSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Open TCP Socket
        /// </summary>
        public void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                SrvSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,_socketPort);
                SrvSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                SrvSocket.Listen(4);
                SrvSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null); //TODO : تست کنم State را یک بار سوکت بگذارم یکبار State خودم
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Socket Exception trown : " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Timeout Exception trown : " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Exception trown : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket ClntSocket = SrvSocket.EndAccept(ar); // روند تایید انجام شد.

                SrvSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null); // ممکنه کلاینت های دیگه هم بخواند وصل بشند

                //SocketState state = new SocketState(); // وضعیت پورت تنظیم میکنیم

                ClntSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length
                    , SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), ClntSocket); // شروع به دریافت میکنیم


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(@"On Accept Exception trown : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket ClntSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int byteReades = ClntSocket.EndReceive(ar);

                if (byteReades > 0)
                {
                    var collectedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteData, 0, byteReades);
                    Console.WriteLine(collectedData);
                }

                ClntSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), ClntSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"On receive Exception trown : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public void Send(string data)
        {
            //var sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            //IPEndPoint ConToSocket = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.101"), 8080);

            //TcpClient Client = new TcpClient(ConToSocket);
            //Client.
        }
        public void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

        }
    }
    public class SocketState
    {
        public Socket TransferSocket = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Buffer Size
        /// </summary>
        public const int bufferSize = 1024;
        /// <summary>
        /// Recieved byte
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        /// <summary>
        /// Offset
        /// </summary>
        public int offset = 0;
    }
}
```

First question: Why can I only connect to the server once?

> I use telnet to connect server on local pc.when i open more telnet no stop all sending !

And this is my Client Class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Tcp
{
    class Client
    {
        Socket ClientSocket = null;
        public void Connect(string RemoteIp, int RemotePort)
        {
            ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint RemoteSrv = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(RemoteIp), RemotePort);
            ClientSocket.BeginConnect(RemoteSrv, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
        }
        public void OnConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                ClientSocket.EndConnect(ar);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Exp Thrown OnConnect : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void Send(string str)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            ClientSocket.BeginSend(data,0,data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);
        }
        public void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                ClientSocket.EndSend(ar);
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Exp Thrown OnSend : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When i Connect to server and see socket state in break point connected socket is not 8080 ! Is it wrong ?
And server can not return received data in Console.Writeline , Where is my issue ?

> var collectedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteData, 0, byteReades);
>                           Console.WriteLine(collectedData);
>
> Why i can not Receive form my Client Class !

Finally i need solution to know best way to Send/Receive Communication between my computer and Device via TCP async.

Thank you.

Comment: For starters, your server only has a *single* receive buffer. That's not going to play well when multiple clients connect.

Comment: "First question: Why can I only connect to the server once?" Propably because you are not properly disposing of the Socket. The rule fo thumb is: Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using the using directive. But that is not the only issue with yoru code, I also noticed quite troublesome exception handling. Here are two articles taht I do link often. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Christopher - `using` *statement*, not `using` directive, I think you're meaning. And it's not *that* common to use that with sockets. (Most socket connections being longer lived than a single send or receive)

Comment: @Christopher Socket should be alive as long as the program is open.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How Can i have multiple buffer ? my you send me some article or sample about it ?

Comment: I increased `SrvSocket.Listen` value to 100 i can connect with more telnet socket !

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever DavisMiller: I realized it would not quite apply with teh sockets too late. Still the points about exception handling stand.